# Submitting a form with ajax to a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with checkboxes on each row for different actions - one of them is print all, which generates a pdf.

Therefore I want to submit the form to a page that opens in a new tab. How can I achieve this?

```js
var form = $("#formname");
var url = "url.php";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        //Success
    }
});
```

Comment: This literally doesn't make sense.  A new tab (which is also a window) cannot be *post*'d to NOR can a *post*'ed response end up populating.

Comment: why can't you do it pn the same page? you can generate a pdf via ajax and make  a download or open it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be easier to modify your HTML code like this:

```
<form target="_blank"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In success block

```html
window.location = './your.pdf';
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Submit that form to server
2. Open a new tab
3. Get data from server